# Assigning every other value in array to a corresponding value in a second array

Tags: java, arrays, int, assign

I have two arrays of ints: mod and score. The elements in score need to be assigned to the elements in mod, but in pairs starting from two.

For example, both 10 and 11 in the score array would equal 0 in the mod array, and 1 in score would equal -5 in mod.

If anyone plays Dungeons and Dragons its the same system as the ability scores and their modifiers.

Here's my two arrays.

```
    int[] mod = {-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5};
    int[] score = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25};
```

Comment: Is it allways 2:1 or will it somewhen be 3:1 or 4:1?

Comment: Why don't you use a `Map<Integer, Integer>`

Comment: @Payton Mock Please post ,what you have tried so far.

Comment: What would map to -4 in mod?  I'm confused because if I look at `score` in pairs, 9 and 10 would both map to -1, but you're saying 10 would map to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `HashMap<Integer,Integer` will do what you need.

For example :

```
Map<Integer,Integer> scoreToMod = new HashMap<>();
...
scoreToMod.put(10,0);
scoreToMod.put(11,0);
...
int mod = scoreToMod.get(11); // will return 0
```

Comment: WOW didn't even think of using HashMap. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a division of ints
ScorePosition/2 is the mapping position for the mod.

So the first two elements of score maps to the first of mid
0/2=0 and 1/2=0
And for the next two:
2/2=1 and 3/2 =1
And so